# Trying to make "register" and "login" anchor tags disappear and "logout" anchor tag appear when signing in

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get the register and login anchor tags to disappear when i sign in and the logout anchor to appear. Login and register stay on the page even after i sign in.

```
<div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <% if (!currentUser) { %>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
      <% } else { %>
      <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
          <% } %>
```

I have access to currentUser through a middleware in express, where i assigned it to req.user

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property *display: none*. And apply a css class dynamically using javascript.

```js
const loginEl = document.getElementById("login-anchor");

//change the class name conditionally
if(condition) {
  loginEl.classList.remove("show-login");
  loginEl.classList.add("hide-login");
}
```

```css
.hide-login {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="show-login" id="login-anchor" href="/login">Login</a>
```